# Trying to remove Super ViewController but stuck in View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 3 ViewControllers 1.Main 2.Gallery 3.Text. What my problem is that i have the GalleryViewController using an External UIView with the name GalleryItemView. So once the view controller calls this inside the UIView i have a button that changes the subview so what i do is use the [super addSubView:newView]; eveything works out great but when i return to the GalleryViewController my app crashes so im guessing im doing this wrong. also what i notice is that once i change Views from pressing the button inside the GalleryViewController takes me to the menu and when i do a swipe gesture it scrolls horizontal and i do have a scrollview in the GalleryViewController Class so maybe what im doing is adding a subview to the ScrollView anyone know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For starters:

```
[super addSubView:newView];
```

is pretty much incorrect.

Adding a view to a viewcontroller, you want to do

```
[self.view addSubview:galleryItemView];  
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:galleryItemView];
```

If you believe you have added it properly, you could do the following to verify it:

```
if ([galleryItemView.superview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
  NSLog(@"galleryItemView's parent is a scrollview"); 
}
```

Please post the crash if you still have problems.

Comment: hello david thanks for your answer i haven't tried it; but i will when i get home. I want to make a note at, where i use [super addSubView:newView]; is on the UIView itself so this stops me from using [self.view addSubview:galleryItemView];  i get a compiler error saying self.view is not in union. the button to change views is on the UIView